# Django forms unit tests with ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-forms, django-testing

I have a `ModelForm` that contains some `ForeignKey`, say to the User object but it could be to any other model. I have a unit test class for this form, but when I am trying to pass it data, I get a `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices` error. The test looks like so:

```
class Monkey(Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Monkey
        fields = ['user', ...]

def test_my_form_with_a_user(self):
    ...
    data = {'user': User.objects.get(pk=1), ... } #  Nope.
    data = {'user': [u'1'], ... } #  Nope.
    data = {'user': [u'JaneDoe'], ... } #  Nope.
    form = MyForm(data, ...)
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid(), form.errors)
    ...
```

I have tried any number of permutation for the `user` but am getting the same error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have other choice fields in the form?

Comment: @LorenzoPeña: Why would it matter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to assign a value to your user field in the test using the following:

```
def test_my_form_with_a_user(self):
    user_pk = User.objects.get(pk=1).pk
    data = {'user': user_pk}
    ...
```

Comment: It did not work at first, then having looked at the form, it did filter some users.  The one (pk=1) was not a valid one. Gah. Got there in the end. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following should avoid the situation where there is no entry with pk=1:

```
def test_my_form_with_a_user(self):
    user_pk = User.objects.all()[0].pk
    data = {'user': user_pk}
```

For example:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> User = get_model_user()
>>> User.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<User: User object (test@example.com)>, <User: User object (a@b.com)>, <User: User object (notarealemail@gmail.com)>]>
>>> User.objects.get(pk=1)
...
accounts.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
>>> User.objects.all()[0]   
<User: User object (test@example.com)>
```